# Adding results from two 'Count' modules in Yahoo Pipes

Tags: yahoo-pipes

How to add (sum up) results from two 'count' modules in Yahoo pipes ?

Suppose one 'count' module displays 4 and other one displays 5, now how can I add these results 4+5

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Connect the first count to the input of a Simple Math and the second count to the value of the same Simple Math.

If you need three counts, then just use another Simple Math with the result of the first Simple Math as the input, and the third count as the value. Repeat to infinity (and beyond).